# Linear and non-differentiable

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

A linear is defined as $$ F (x_1+x_2)=F (x_1)+F (x_2).$$
I want to see is there a linear function but non-differentiable?
If it is please offer an example.

Comment: This kind of example can only occur in infinite dimension spaces.

Comment: That's an additive function, not a linear function

Answer (score 2):

On polynomial space with the norm $N(P)=\int_0^1 P^2$. $P\mapsto P(1)$ is a linear form. But if it is continuous then let's says its norm is $C$ and we have with $P=X^n$,
$$ 1\leq \frac{C}{2n+1}$$
for all $n$. Absurd.